# GUI client for SVN for Windows that integrates with Visual Web Developer 2010 & older Express editions

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-studio-express

I'm looking for a GUI client for SVN that:

1) *Has a GUI for repository interaction. This is my primary requirement. It may or may not have a Visual Studio or Visual Studio Express plug-in.*

**Reason:** I've worked in the past for various employers who all had Visual Studio licenses and I used all kinds of clients for SVN and CVS because most of them integrated with Visual Studio.

Now I am a freelancer working on my own and can't afford Visual Studio licenses so I use the Express editions. I am not sure if, say, TortoiseSVN integrates with Visual Web Developer 2010 or Visual C# 2008 Express. I've only tried TortoiseSVN with VS 2010 Ultimate and VS 2008 Enterprise.

So, Visual Studio support is not that critical a requirement of mine because today I have express versions, tomorrow I might work for another client that gives me a license to Visual Studio and I might have to work with that version of Visual Studio.

My primary goal is to have a GUI client so I can use source control.

2) *If it is to have VS integration, it should be able to integrate with all (including Express editions) of VS.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/). It's the best standalone SVN client for Windows.
2. Microsoft does not allow to use 3rd party extensions with Visual Studio Express / Visual Web Developer.